# Grading weight not calculating correctly

Tags: java, math

```
public class FinalMarkCalculator
{
/**
 * This method is used to caculate the students mark
 */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Assigning the string a variable that holds the students name 
        String studentName;

        //Initalizing a keyboard scanner
        Scanner keyboardStudentName = new Scanner(System.in);

        //System printing out the question
        System.out.print("Enter the students name: ");

        //Assigns the string studentName to the users input
        studentName = keyboardStudentName.nextLine();

        //Assigning the double a variable that hold the students assignment marks as a integer
        double assignmentMarks;

        //Assigning the string a variable that hold the students assignment marks
        String assignmentMarksInput;

        //Initalizing a keyboard scanner with the variable
        Scanner keyboardAssignmentMarks = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Asking the user for assingment marks while printing students name
        System.out.printf("Enter %s's mark for Assignments (Max. 140): ", studentName);

        //Taking the user input and assigning it to our string assignmentMarksInput
        assignmentMarksInput = keyboardAssignmentMarks.nextLine();

        //Converting the user input from a string to a double
        assignmentMarks = Double.parseDouble(assignmentMarksInput);

        //Assigning the double a variable that hold the students Mid-Term exam marks as a integer
        double midTermExamMark;

        //Assigning the string a variable that hold the students assignment marks from user input
        String midTermExamMarkInput;

        //Initalizing a keyboard scanner with the variable
        Scanner keyboardExamMidTermMark = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Asking the user for the Mid-Term Exam mark while printing students name
        System.out.printf("Enter %s's mark for Mid-Term Exam (Max. 60): ", studentName);

        //Taking the user input and assigning it to our midTermExamMarkInput
        midTermExamMarkInput = keyboardExamMidTermMark.nextLine();

        //Converting the user input from a string to a double
        midTermExamMark = Double.parseDouble(midTermExamMarkInput);

        //Assigning the double a variable that hold the students Mid-Term exam marks as a integer
        double finalExamMark;

        //Assigning the string a variable that hold the students assignment marks from user input
        String finalExamMarkInput;

        //Initalizing a keyboard scanner with the variable
        Scanner keyboardFinalExamMark = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Asking the user for the Mid-Term Exam mark while printing students name
        System.out.printf("Enter %s's mark for Final Exam (Max. 85): ", studentName);

        //Taking the user input and assigning it to our midTermExamMarkInput
        finalExamMarkInput = keyboardFinalExamMark.nextLine();

        //Converting the user input from a string to a double
        finalExamMark = Double.parseDouble(finalExamMarkInput);


        //Printing grade report title
        System.out.println("Grade report" + "\n------------");

        //Printing the students name
        System.out.println(studentName + "\n");

        //Printing the assignments mark
        System.out.printf("%.2f/140 worth 15%%\n", assignmentMarks);

        //Printing the Mid-Term exam mark
        System.out.printf("%.2f/60 worth 40%%\n", midTermExamMark);

        //Printing the Final exam mark
        System.out.printf("%.2f/85 worth 45%%\n", finalExamMark);

        double finalMark = (assignmentMarks*.15)+(midTermExamMark*.40)+(finalExamMark*.45);

        //Printing the total calculated final mark
        System.out.printf("\n\nFinal Mark: " + finalMark);            
    }
}
```

My code runs fine but it does not do the math correctly and I can't seem to figure out why even if I put everything perfect it still doesn't equal 100%.

This is the equation I'm using and I think this is how it should be done:

```
(assignmentMarks*.15)+(midTermExamMark*.40)+(finalExamMark*.45)
```

Comment: Fora start, you do not need multiple Scanner Objects, just re-use

Comment: could i see an example of this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maths should be

```
 double finalMark = (assignmentMarks/140*15)+(midTermExamMark/60*40)+(finalExamMark/85*45);
```

Also I think it is better to not declare (and then later) initialize your variables - do in one step

```
double assignmentMarks = Double.parseDouble(assignmentMarksInput);
```

Also just use one Scanner

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and use it for all input

```
String studentName = scanner.nextLine();
....
String assignmentMarksInput = scanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: oh okay thank you so much, I will work on formatting that better